Azure DevOps Pipeline Failure "User '1a5add63-xxxxxxx' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'."
I have an Azure DevOps pipeline which runs on a self-hosted build agent, which has started failing on the Restore step. There is a Nuget.config file for the solution, with a reference to my own Artifacts feed, and a placeholder in the package credentials, which is replaced with a PAT token by the pipeline in the first step. This is the error in the pipeline run:
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myOrganisation/_packaging/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'. (DevOps Activity ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)).

The user ID given doesn't match any in my Azure AD tenant, nor my organisation, it doesn't appear in the user list when I try to add a new user to the Artifacts Feed, and I haven't yet found a CLI command that can identify it.
I've tried:

Generating a new PAT to be injected into the nuget.config with package read permissions
Re-installing the build agent
Using an Azure-hosted build agent
Adding ALL users that are available as readers of the Artifact feed
Running VS on my build agent via remote desktop and restore/rebuild solution works fine
Running this command just hangs


Which PAT(scopes) did you use during self-hosted agent registration?

Packages (Read) and Build (Read/Write). But also, I used the Azure-hosted agent and it had the same problem.

If your private Artifacts feed is in the same Azure DevOps organization with the pipeline, you can use the System.AccessToken instead of your PAT to authorize.

Go to "Project Settings" (and "Organization Settings") > "Settings" under "Pipelines" section, ensure the following two options are disabled (Off).

Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines
Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines



Open the Artifacts feed and go to "Feed Settings" > "Permissions". Ensure the following two build identities has been assigned with the role "Feed and Upstream Reader (Collaborator)" at least so that the pipelines can read packages from the feed. If you also want to publish new packages to the feed from pipelines, you should assign the "Feed Publisher (Contributor)" role at least. See "Job access tokens".

Project Collection Build Service ({Organization Name})
{Project Name} Build Service ({Organization Name})



In the nuget.config file, you do not need to configure credentials for the feed under the "<packageSourceCredentials>" section.
...
  <packageSources>
    <!-- Add nuget.org as a package source. -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- Add the private Artifacts feed as a package source. -->
    <add key="myPrivateFeed" value="{URL to connect to the feed}" />
  </packageSources>
. . .


In the pipeline, you can configure the restore task like as below. Here I use dotnet restore as example. Can use the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to execute the dotnet restore.
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '{path to the csproj or sln file(s)}'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: 'path/to/nuget.config'



With this configuration, since the private feed set in the nuget.config file is in the same organization with the pipeline, the pipeline will use "System.AccessToken" to access the feed.

If the private feed is outside of current organization where the pipeline is in, you have two ways to configure.
Use NuGet service connection to access the external feeds:

Go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections", create NuGet service connections to connect to the external feeds. Ensure the username and password/PAT set on the service connections has the role permissions to access the packages in the external feeds.


In the nuget.config file, you do not need to configure credentials for the feed under the "<packageSourceCredentials>" section.
...
  <packageSources>
    <!-- Add nuget.org as a package source. -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- Add the private Artifacts feeds as package sources. -->
    <add key="ExternalFeed01" value="{URL to connect to the feed}" />
    <add key="ExternalFeed02" value="{URL to connect to the feed}" />
  </packageSources>
. . .


In the pipeline, you can configure the restore task like as below.
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '{path to the csproj or sln file(s)}'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: 'path/to/nuget.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'ExternalNugetFeed01, ExternalNugetFeed02'



Directly use the password/PAT without NuGet service connection in pipeline to access the external feeds.

In the nuget.config file, you need to configure credentials for the feeds under the "<packageSourceCredentials>" section. You can use environment variables (%ENV_VAR_NAME%) in the file instead of explicitly filling the sensitive information (such as password/PAT) into the file. See "nuget.config reference".
...
  <packageSources>
    <!-- Add nuget.org as a package source. -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- Add the private Artifacts feeds as package sources. -->
    <add key="ExternalFeed01" value="{URL to connect to the feed}" />
    <add key="ExternalFeed02" value="{URL to connect to the feed}" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <ExternalFeed01>
      <add key="Username" value="%FEED01_USERNAME%" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%FEED01_PASSWORD%" />
      <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
    </ExternalFeed01>
    <ExternalFeed02>
      <add key="Username" value="%FEED02_USERNAME%" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%FEED02_PASSWORD%" />
      <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
    </ExternalFeed02>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
. . .


Add the sensitive information as secret variables in the pipeline.


In the pipeline, you can use the script task (such as Bash, PowerShell or CmdLine) to execute the 'dotnet restore' command, and use the 'env' key on the task to map the secret variables as environment variables.
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  env:
    FEED01_USERNAME: $(feed01_username)
    FEED01_PASSWORD: $(feed01_password)
    FEED02_USERNAME: $(feed02_username)
    FEED02_PASSWORD: $(feed02_password)
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: dotnet restore '{path to the csproj or sln file(s)}' --configfile 'path/to/nuget.config'




